# AJAX (JQuery): Cookies are not being sent

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies

I'm sending a GET request using AJAX and jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: "http://third-party-website.com",
        dataType: "text",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("end");
        }
    });
});
```

And cookies are not being sent. Why?

Comment: The Cookie is a secret between your server and the client.
I think it is a security-problem when you send your cookie to a third party.

Comment: I know it. But it's the only way of accessing to the http://third-party-website.com. It's going to be used for automatization purposes.

Comment: And how is this supposed to work? 
How is the cookie used in the thirdParty Website?

And CORS could also be a problem depending on the thirdParty setup.
But i am not  familiar with this, so just ignore me if you do know what you are doing.